# Problems in injecting entity manager into stateless bean

Tags: java-ee-6

I am developing an EJB3-app, where I use stateless beans. It seems like the `EntityManager` is not injected properly into my bean.

Here is code for the stateless bean:

```
@Stateless
@LocalBean
public class FirmEJB {

    @PersistenceContext(unitName = "Fr14_07_Nezdolij_lab3PU")
    private EntityManager em;

    @PersistenceUnit(unitName="Fr14_07_Nezdolij_lab3PU")
    private EntityManagerFactory emf;

    public FirmEJB() {
        emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("Fr14_07_Nezdolij_lab3PU");
        em = emf.createEntityManager();
    }

    public EntityManager getEm() {
        return em;
    }

    public void setEm(EntityManager em) {
        this.em = em;
    }

    public Employee createEmployee(Employee e){
        em.persist(e);
        return e;
    }

    public Project createProject(Project p){
        em.persist(p);
        return p;
    }

    public Customer createProject(Customer c){
        em.persist(c);
        return c;
    }

    public Department createProject(Department d){
        em.persist(d);
        return d;
    }

    public ProjectManager createProjectManager(ProjectManager prjman){
        em.persist(prjman);
        return prjman;
    }

}
```

When I try to create an instance of `FirmEJB I` get the following exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at sttls.FirmEJB.createEmployee(FirmEJB.java:42)
    at entity.Main.main(Main.java:33)
```

**persistence.xml**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd">
    <persistence-unit name="Fr14_07_Nezdolij_lab3PU" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
        <provider>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider</provider>
        <jta-data-source>jdbc/fir</jta-data-source>
        <exclude-unlisted-classes>false</exclude-unlisted-classes>
        <properties>
            <property name="eclipselink.ddl-generation" value="create-tables"/>
            <property name="eclipselink.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/firmDB;create=true"/>
            <property name="eclipselink.jdbc.user" value="admin"/>
            <property name="eclipselink.jdbc.password" value="admin"/>
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

**Client code**:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws ClassNotFoundException, Exception {

    Employee emp1 = new Employee("Alan", "Smith");

    FirmEJB firmejb = new FirmEJB();
    firmejb.createEmployee(emp1);
}
```

Comment: What is your `entity.Main.main(Main.java:33)`? Is this your `static void main` method executed from Java SE? Are you using any Java EE 6 container to run your code?

Comment: I've just added a public constructor and private EntityManagerFactory field to FirmEJB class, now FirmEJB is properly initialized, but persistence doesn't work in FirmEJB methods...

Comment: Yes, I'm using Java EE 6 container and I call FirmEJB from JavaSE main() method. Is it invalid?

Comment: You should post your client code to show us how you're executing the FirmEJB. Also please post your `persistence.xml` for clearance.

Comment: I've also changed code in FirmEJB class.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're using Java EE features in Java SE environment. **That won't work.**

The Java EE container responsible for dependency injection, so the `PersisteneContext` and `PersistenceUnit` make any sense only in the Java EE container environment (like Glassfish or JBoss).

If you define something like this:

```
@PersistenceContext(unitName = "Fr14_07_Nezdolij_lab3PU")
private EntityManager em;

@PersistenceUnit(unitName="Fr14_07_Nezdolij_lab3PU")
private EntityManagerFactory emf;

public FirmEJB() {
    emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("Fr14_07_Nezdolij_lab3PU");
    em = emf.createEntityManager();
}
```

you're defining dependency injection through annotations and at the same time you create the instances of EMF and EM by yourself. The annotations are **meaningless** in your case.

Moreover:

- in `persistence.xml` you're defining to use `RESOURCE_LOCAL` transaction type and at the same time you're defining `<jta-data-source>` element (which means that you'll be using JTA transactions),
- I assume that you're using EclipseLink so the `<exclude-unlisted-classes>false</exclude-unlisted-classes>` is working. Beware that this is not a portable solution - in order to be sure that in Java SE environment your entities will be visible to the JPA provider, you should define them using `<class>` element.

And last but not least, if you're executing your code in Java SE environment like this and don't start any Embedded EJB container than `@Stateless` is not needed because your class **doesn't have any EJB nature**. POJO annotated as a `@Stateless` or `@Stateful` gains EJB nature by being executed in EJB container. In this case, it acts like a plain Java class.

Beware - even if you'd use Embedded EJB container the code you've shown will **not** instantiate an EJB. You cannot use `new FirmEJB()` with EJBs. The container should be responsible for providing you an instance of the EJB.
That's the whole point of the abstraction - you depend upon abstraction rather than creation.

You might be interested in further reading like OpenJPA [JPA Concepts](http://openejb.apache.org/jpa-concepts.html) or [OpenEJB Documentation](http://openejb.apache.org/documentation.html).

Comment: Also, please define what does "persistence doesn't work in FirmEJB methods" mean.

Comment: it doesn't persist entities into tables. In my client code example, all tables are created, but Employee emp1 is not in the table Employees, though I call firmejb.createEmployee(emp1);

Comment: It's probably because you don't commit your transaction. If you use `RESOURCE_LOCAL` transaction type it means that you need to fetch `EntityTransaction` by `EntityManager#getTransaction` and use it: `begin()` at the beginning of your transaction and `commit()` after the changes are made.

Comment: Ok, I see. Is it normal then to use Persistence API in JavaSE?

Comment: Yes, it is. You're just using it differently. I think you should read what are the differences between EJB and JPA. You don't need EJB to work with JPA. Both - EJB and JPA can be used in Java SE (i.e. EJB through Embedded contaiener and JPA using `RESOURCE_LOCAL` Entity Managers.). Hope it makes it clear :-)

Comment: @Kate - no problem. If it was helpful and answered your problem feel free to mark it as accepted answer. If you have any doubts please refer to [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work).

Answer (score 0):

yon need a change `transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL" to transaction-type="JTA"`

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer!